# HTML Auto-Play a song and StartAt

Tags: html, html5-audio

I have this code, but I do not know how to make the song start from 0:19 seconds. Could you help me out?

```
<div class="fin-subheading">
  &middot; ROLEPLAY &middot;
  <audio id='music' volume='0.5' autoplay controls>
    <source src="anonymous.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  </audio>
</div>

<script>
  var audio = document.getElementById("music");
  audio.volume = 0.3;
</script>
```

Comment: See if my answer helps :) Do also Vote and Accept if it does help:) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a playback range in the `src` attribute itself. See the docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Audio_and_video_delivery#specifying_playback_range):

> When specifying the URI of media for an  or  element,
> you can optionally include additional information to specify the
> portion of the media to play. To do this, append a hash mark ("#")
> followed by the media fragment description.
>
> A time range is specified using the syntax:
>
> #t=[starttime][,endtime]

So instead of:

```
<source src="anonymous.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
```

simply put:

```
<source src="anonymous.mp3#t=n,m" type="audio/mpeg">
```

where `n` and `m` are the start and end times, respectively.

The range can also be unbounded as well. So you could, for instance do this:

```
<source src="anonymous.mp3#t=19" type="audio/mpeg">
```

which will start at 19 seconds and play through till the end; or even this:

```
<source src="anonymous.mp3#t=,19" type="audio/mpeg">
```

which will start from the beginning through 19 seconds.

Comment: How could it be? For example:
source src="anonymous.mp3#t=19,m" type="audio/mpeg">

Comment: It can be unbounded as well, just put `src="anonymous.mp3#t=19"` -- which will play through to the end.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `currentTime` property

```js
window.onload = function() {
    const audio = document.getElementById("music");
    audio.volume = 0.3;
    audio.currentTime = 19;
    audio.play();
}
```

Comment: Can I make it like this?
audio.volume = 0.3;
audio.currentTime = 19;
audio.play();

Comment: @InNovAqua yes you can. I hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `canplaythrough` event and within that `currentTime` and then `play` when that time is reached.

Make sure you do not `autoplay` in the audio tag in HTML.

```html
<audio id="audio2" 
       preload="auto" 
       src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a9/Tromboon-sample.ogg" >
    <p>Your browser does not support the audio element</p>
</audio>

<script>
    myAudio=document.getElementById('audio2');
    myAudio.addEventListener('canplaythrough', function() {
      this.currentTime = 19;
      this.play();
    });
</script>
```